# Sorting file based on input value in opening string

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, grep

I have a file with below format, I need to read the strings which start with '>' and sort the lines based on OS= in alphabetical order.

```
>Mdm2 OS=Macaca nemestrina OX=9545 GN=MDM2 PE=3 SV=1
MVRSRQMCNTNMSVPTDGAVTTSQIPASEQETLVRPKPLLLKLLKSVGAQKDTYTMKEVL
FYLGQYIMTKRLYDEKQQHIVYCSNDLLGDLFGVPSFSVKEHRKIYTMIYRNLVVVNQQE
>Mdm2 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9545 GN=MDM2 PE=3 SV=1
SSDSGTSVSENRCHLEGGSDQKDLVQELQEEKPSSSHLVSRPSTSSRRRAISETEENSDE
>Mdm2 OS=Felis catus OX=9685 GN=MDM2 PE=4 SV=2
MSRGFRRAPLGQQGARIGRASAGSGPPGACAGPVWLERKWSKSPSLRGSPNPSDRSPAGF
AARSL
```

Desired Output :

```
>Mdm2 OS=Felis catus OX=9685 GN=MDM2 PE=4 SV=2
MSRGFRRAPLGQQGARIGRASAGSGPPGACAGPVWLERKWSKSPSLRGSPNPSDRSPAGF
AARSL
>Mdm2 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9545 GN=MDM2 PE=3 SV=1
SSDSGTSVSENRCHLEGGSDQKDLVQELQEEKPSSSHLVSRPSTSSRRRAISETEENSDE
>Mdm2 OS=Macaca nemestrina OX=9545 GN=MDM2 PE=3 SV=1
MVRSRQMCNTNMSVPTDGAVTTSQIPASEQETLVRPKPLLLKLLKSVGAQKDTYTMKEVL
FYLGQYIMTKRLYDEKQQHIVYCSNDLLGDLFGVPSFSVKEHRKIYTMIYRNLVVVNQQE
```

My code so far is:

```
while read p;
if [[ $p == >* ]];
then
#what should I do here to sort the line by OS ? 

done <input.txt
```

Comment: @John1024 I added the code whatever I tried.I am having issue to how just read the line and sort based on OX value

Comment: @Amessihel It is fasta format ,and I have added what I have tried.

Comment: @shome Are the `OS` values unique?  Or, might they be repeated?

Comment: They are unique @John1024

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
/^>/{
  if(val){
    print val}
    val=""
  }
  {
    val=(val?val "##":"")$0
  }
END{
    if(val){
      print val
    }
}' Input_file | sort -k2.4 | tr -s '##' '\n'
```

***Explanation:*** Considering that your Input_file  doesn't have `##` in them, else you can change them to any other string. Basically I am adding lines starting from `>` to till last line that are coming before next occurrence of `>` where I am adding them to a single line by `##` separator(you could change it which I mentioned  already) then sorting them with 2nd field, finally removing `##` by `tr` command to new line again.

***Output will be as follows(after running for provided samples):***

```
>Mdm2 OS=Felis catus OX=9685 GN=MDM2 PE=4 SV=2
MSRGFRRAPLGQQGARIGRASAGSGPPGACAGPVWLERKWSKSPSLRGSPNPSDRSPAGF
AARSL
>Mdm2 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9545 GN=MDM2 PE=3 SV=1
SSDSGTSVSENRCHLEGGSDQKDLVQELQEEKPSSSHLVSRPSTSSRRRAISETEENSDE
>Mdm2 OS=Macaca nemestrina OX=9545 GN=MDM2 PE=3 SV=1
MVRSRQMCNTNMSVPTDGAVTTSQIPASEQETLVRPKPLLLKLLKSVGAQKDTYTMKEVL
FYLGQYIMTKRLYDEKQQHIVYCSNDLLGDLFGVPSFSVKEHRKIYTMIYRNLVVVNQQE
```